# HStack Scroll View Squishes my AVPlayer Views and its overlay text

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this horizontal scroll view in my app which plays three separate videos:

[image]

But as you can see, the text goes out of bounds. Even the width of each Card isn't uniform. This wasn't the case when I only put one of these videoCards on the screen. Why is that happening and how do I fix it?

My Scroll View for the video cards looks like this:

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 40) {
                    ForEach(videoManager.videos) { video in
                        RecentCard(video: video)
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: videoManager.videos) { _ in
                    print("VM loaded Recents Videos")
                }
                
            }
```

and each VideoCard (I call them recentCards), looks like this:

```
struct RecentCard: View {
    @State private var player = AVPlayer()
    @State private var playToggle: Bool = true
    @State var video: VideoModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            videoPlayer
            
            textOverlay
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 300, alignment: .leading)
        .background(.thinMaterial, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
        .cornerRadius(20)
    }
    
    
    var videoPlayer: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: player)
            .scaledToFill()
            .onAppear {
                player = AVPlayer(url: video.videoUrlPath!)
                player.play()
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                if playToggle == false {
                    player.play()
                    playToggle = true
                } else {
                    player.pause()
                    playToggle = false
                }
                let impactHeavy = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
                impactHeavy.impactOccurred()
            }
            .opacity(0.56)
            .background(.ultraThinMaterial)

    }
    
    var textOverlay: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(video.title)
                .font(.title.bold())
                .textCase(.uppercase)
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(video.title2)
                    .font(.body)
                Text("\(video.viewCount) Views")
                    .font(.body)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottomTrailing)
                    .padding(15)
                    .offset(x: 10)
                //Text(vManager.video.videoUrlPath?.absoluteString ?? "NIL")
            }
            .opacity(0.67)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 200, alignment: .topLeading)
        .padding()
        .offset(y: 10)
        .foregroundColor(.white)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is aspect fill of videoPlayer, it expands ZStack in which text "overlay" is placed, and only then limited by frame.

Instead use real overlay to the resulted limited frame, like

```
 videoPlayer
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 300, alignment: .leading)
    .overlay(textOverlay, alignment: .topLeading)   // or .top        << here !!
```